# iPhone 5c unsupported upgrade possible?

Tags: iphone, ios

In case that made absolutely no sense, what I mean is, is it possible to put an unsupported iOS on the ***iPhone 5c*** **without a jailbreak**?

What I have found out is that a .ipsw is like the OS, but for a specific phone. What I want to do is put an **iPhone 7/8 Plus** ipsw on the **5c**.

Is it possible to do so with a computer running macOS Monterey (12.2 beta)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> is it possible to put an unsupported iOS on the iPhone 5c without a jailbreak?

and

> What I want to do is put an iPhone 7/8 Plus ipsw on the 5c.

Short answer, **no**.

IPSW files are custom build of iOS for specific models of iOS devices. The latest version of iOS supported by iPhone 5c is iOS 10.3.3. So it's not possible to upgrade it to a later version of iOS.

Even for iOS version 10.3.3 or earlier, you should use the IPSW file build for your specific model of iOS device/iPhone.